# What is the latest valid release of kernel 2.4

Tags: kernel

I want to download the latest valid release of kernel 2.4.

I look at ftp.kernel.org and here the highest release available is [2.4.31](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/linux-2.4.31.tar.gz), while searching on others mirrors I found that ther is also higest release, until  [2.4.37.9](ftp://ftp.task.gda.pl/mirror/ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/linux-2.4.37.9.tar.bz2) and on some other site they spoke about a 2.4.37.11 release ( ss. linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Operating-Systems/Kernels/Linux-Kernel-2-4-3022.shtml ).

I'm wondering why the official repository didn't list the releases above 2.4.31.
Are these release unofficial or not approved or something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google will find an LKML post by Willy Tarreau (maintainer) announcing the release of 2.4.37.11. Looks official enough.

Comment: Tanks.  I need to know if these alst release ( I already have the 2.4.3.9 ) is valid.  I wondering that because I didn't see they on the official kernel site and so I suspected they should be a fakes.

Answer (score 3):

We are still restoring some of the older release tarballs at this time. Due to the changes in the way [PGP signatures are done](https://www.kernel.org/signature.html), maintainers must re-upload these files on their own. We cannot do it for them.

In the meantime, your best bet to get older tarball releases is to clone the [2.4 git repository](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/wtarreau/linux-2.4.git;a=summary) and run "git archive".

E.g.:

```
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/wtarreau/linux-2.4.git
$ cd linux-2.4/
$ git archive --format=tar.gz --prefix=linux-2.4.37.11/ -o ../linux-2.4.37.11.tar.gz v2.4.37.11
```

Comment: On old machine running redhat 7.3 , where kernel 2.4 is required, git is not working.

Comment: So the release 2.4.37.9 , whicn I still have dowloaded tiem ago, is a valid release ?

Comment: @enzo2 yes, anything you downloaded from ftp.kernel.org is a valid and verified release. If git is not working on an RH 7.3 system (my god, why?), run the commands on some other system and scp over. Git has been ported to almost every possible architecture.

Comment: RH 7.3 is a very old release ( year 2002 ).  If you known about a git working on it, please let me known.